# How to use image_cropper in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, package, image-cropper

It's said in the description of the package that is supports web. But since it's not possible to get path of the file in flutter web I can't to use it. Because the only way to work with this package is to provide path of the image

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the example and you have to use Image.network instead of Image.file on web.

Then you can pass in the url to the image like this:

```
Image.network(
   url,
);
```

Comment: Can you provide the example? Because I don't see it

Comment: Here's the link to the example: https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper/example

Comment: I mean I've to provide 'sourcePath' to the image I am working with. Image.network is for the placeholder

Comment: Well they use the image_picker package to pick images from the device, and that package apparently works with web. I never used the package for web before but maybe there pops up a browse window or something so I think you can upload images on web

Answer (score 0):

if you what to crop image than check out [crop_image](https://pub.dev/packages/crop_image) package

Answer (score 0):

In the image_cropper: ^5.0.1 version you can use kIsWeb to check if the running is compiling for the web and  Image.network(path) to display the image as it should.

`kIsWeb ? Image.network(path) : Image.file(File(path))`

don't forget to add :

```html
<head>
  ....

  <!-- Croppie -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/croppie/2.6.5/croppie.css" />
  <script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/exif-js/2.3.0/exif.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/croppie/2.6.5/croppie.min.js"></script>

  ....
</head>
```

more detail: https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper#web